# Usar FullCalendar 3.9.0

Tags: php

Segui este tutorial para criar a minha agenda:
https://medium.com/@guimenegussi/criando-um-calend%C3%A1rio-de-eventos-din%C3%A2micos-com-php-ajax-e-fullcalendar-js-6cc21634b1a4

Depois fiz download do fullcalendar-3.9.0.zip neste link:
https://fullcalendar.io/download

Depois do download que ficheiros tenho de copiar desta pasta que fiz download e em que caminho tenho de colar dentro do meu tema ou do servidor?

É que na console recebo estes erros:

> agenda-teste:388 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js
>   404 (Not Found) agenda-teste:389 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js
>   404 (Not Found) agenda-teste:386 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css
>   404 (Not Found) agenda-teste:387 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js
>   404 (Not Found) agenda-teste:388 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx5/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js
>   404 (Not Found) agenda-teste:389 GET
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js
>   404 (Not Found)

Já tentei copiar e colar em todos os sitios dentro do meu tema e continuam sempre aparecerem estes erros, e desta forma não me retorna o calendário.

Resolução do problema:
Os caminhos estavam errados das librarias:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.css' /> 
<script src='/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script src='/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script> 
<script src='/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

Comment: No link do arquivo `js` aparece `index.php`. A credito que o caminho correto deveria ser mais ou menos assim: `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js`.

Comment: @Thiago Magalhães, como posso então colocar assim o caminho?

Comment: como está fazendo a chamada desses arquivos?

Comment: Desta forma:   <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
 <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>

Comment: tente dessas duas forma:
`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wordpress/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />` ou `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />`

Comment: @Thiago Magalhães, resolvido, os problemas estavam nos caminhos

Comment: como você resolveu?

Comment: alterando os caminhos como você comentou em cima

Comment: poste e marque como resposta o modo como resolveu o problema para poder fechar a pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81289/discussion-between-iniciante-and-thiago-magalhaes).